# Limit of the $n^{2}\left( \ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) -\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can one compute the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n^{2}\left(  \ln\left(  1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \quad ?
$$
I wrote

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n^{2}\left(  \ln\left(  1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)  =\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left(  1+x\right)
-x}{x^{2}}\overset{l^{\prime}H}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{1+x}%
-1}{2x}\overset{l^{\prime}H}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{-1}{2\left(
1+x\right)  ^{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
But how can be a limit of a positive sequence be negative?

Comment: Where does $\ln(1+x)-x$ come from?

Comment: If you know that $\ln(1+1/n)=1/n-1/(2n^2)+o(1/n^2)$, you may be able to finish with it.

Comment: You have a few mistakes. If you let $\dfrac{1}{n} = x$, then what you should be evaluating is $$\dfrac{\log(1+x) - \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}}{x^2} = \dfrac{\log(1+x) + \dfrac{1}{1+x} - 1}{x^2}$$ I believe.

Comment: Good sleuthing @MartinR .

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Easy with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%2B%5Cinfty%7Dn%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(%20%20%5Cln%5Cleft(%20%201%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%20-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1).

Comment: @MartinR holy crap this is amazing. I wish I had known about it sooner. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969. – But don't worry: Many high-rep users are unable (or unwilling) to search for duplicates)!

Comment: Thank you for suggestions and Approacho!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}n^{2}\left(  \ln\left(  1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) 
$$
$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \left( n^2 \ln\left(  1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
-n\frac{1}{1+\frac1n}\right)
$$

$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \left(n^2\left[ \dfrac1n-\dfrac1{2n^2}+O\left(\dfrac1{n^3}\right)\right]-
n\left[1-\dfrac1n+O\left(\dfrac1n\right)\right]\right)=
$$

$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \left( \left[ n-\dfrac1{2 }+O\left(\dfrac1{n}\right)\right]-
 \left[n-1+O\left(\dfrac1n\right)\right]\right)=\dfrac12
$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\dfrac1n=h,\dfrac1{1+n}=\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1h}=\dfrac h{h+1}$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)-\dfrac h{h+1}}{h^2}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)-h}{h^2}+\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h-\dfrac h{h+1}}{h^2}$$

Use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) to find the first limit  $=-\dfrac12$

For the second, its $=1$ right?